# 32 bit compiler that generate 64 bit code

Tags: visual-studio-2012

I read about various command line tools of Visual studio.

VS2012 x64 Cross Tool Command Prompt
VS2012 x86 Native Tool Command Prompt
VS2012 x64 Native Tool Command Prompt

1) 32 bit compiler that generates 64 bit code

2) 32 bit compiler that generates 32 bit code

3) 64 bit compiler that generates 64 bit code

What is the difference between above three? What does it mean by "32 bit compiler" and "64 bit code"?

Comment: It should make no difference if you compile the code from 32 bit or 64 bit to 64 bit. It just compiles it the same way. You just can't run it in your 32 bit machine.

Comment: @JanPeter: That's not correct. The 64-bit compiler employs different limits for arrays, for example. Even though both the 32-bit cross-compiler and the 64-bit compiler should produce the same code, they don't. I'm not aware of a full list of differences, though.